# Having trouble adding a 24 hour voting system?

Tags: php, mysql, database, hour

There is a script that triggers the code below

I want to disallow executing the script more than once per 24 hours.

I wanted this script to store the last visit time in a table against the user id in a database, then do a time calculation and back them out until the 24 hour expiry time.

Can someone explain how to do this? It would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me with this?

```
<?php
//Input correct values into this section
$dbhost = '888888';
$dbuser = '888888';
$dbpass = '888888';
$dbname = '888888';
$dbtable = 'redeem';
$dbtable2 = 'playersthatvoted';
//------------------------------------
$input = 'diamond 12';
$player = $_POST['Player'];
$time = time();
if(!isset($_COOKIE['24Hourvote'])){
   //---- This is the connection
   $conn = mysql_connect ($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db($dbname);
   $query1 = "INSERT INTO `".$dbname."`.`".$dbtable."` (`player`, `item`) VALUES ('".$player."', '".$input."')";
   $query2 = "INSERT INTO `".$dbname."`.`".$dbtable2."` (`player`, `time`) VALUES ('".$player."', '".$time."')";
   mysql_query($query1);
   mysql_query($query2);
   $query= 'SELECT `player` FROM `playersthatvoted` ASC LIMIT 0, 10 ';
   $result = mysql_query($query);
   mysql_close($conn);
   echo 'Done! Type /redeem in-game to get your diamonds.';
   $ip=@$REMOTE_ADDR;
   setcookie ("24Hourvote",$ip,time()+86400,'/',true,…
} else {
   echo 'You have already voted today! Come back later...'; }
?>
```

EDIT: and could I make it so that it displays the time left until the user can vote again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952248/i-need-assistance-with-my-php-script-this-is-simple-and-pays-20-dollars

Comment: no, I reposted and asked more sensible questions, and offered no money.

Comment: You need to read up on SQL injection. Also, `$var = "INSERT INTO $dbname.$dbtable ..."` is valid syntax. I have no idea who gave you the idea that `"foo $bar baz"` should be `"foo".$bar."baz"`, but it shouldn't—its unreadable.

Comment: Also, you should visit our [Code Review site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq), there are a lot of ways that snippet could be improved.

Comment: You need to use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` instead of `$REMOTE_ADDR` unless *register_globals* is enabled - and that setting is deprecated and horribly bad so it should be disabled at all times!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
//Input correct values into this section
$dbhost = '888888';
$dbuser = '888888';
$dbpass = '888888';
$dbname = '888888';
$dbtable = 'redeem';
$dbtable2 = 'playersthatvoted';
//------------------------------------
$input = 'diamond 12';
$time = time();
if(!isset($_COOKIE['24Hourvote'])){
       $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
   //---- This is the connection
   $conn = mysql_connect ($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db($dbname);

      // Escape all user entered data always
      $player = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Player']);

   // Select time for this player if available
   $query = "SELECT time FROM playersthatvoted WHERE player = '$player' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 0, 1";
   $result = mysql_query($query);

   if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 0)
   {
       $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
       $last_visit = $row[0];
       $vote_allowed_time = $last_visit + 86400; 

       // Allowed to vote
       if($time > $vote_allowed_time)
       {
           // Do whatever else you need to here ...

           setcookie ("24Hourvote",$ip,time()+86400,'/');
       }
       else
       {
           echo 'This player has already voted today! Come back later...';
       }
   }
   else
   {
       $query1 = "INSERT INTO `".$dbname."`.`".$dbtable."` (`player`, `item`) VALUES ('".$player."', '".$input."')";
       $query2 = "INSERT INTO `".$dbname."`.`".$dbtable2."` (`player`, `time`) VALUES ('".$player."', '".$time."')";
       mysql_query($query1);
       mysql_query($query2);
       $query= 'SELECT `player` FROM `playersthatvoted` ASC LIMIT 0, 10 ';
       $result = mysql_query($query);
       mysql_close($conn);
       echo 'Done! Type /redeem in-game to get your diamonds.';

       setcookie ("24Hourvote",$ip,time()+86400,'/');
   }
} else {
   echo 'You have already voted today! Come back later...'; }
?>
```

Note: Never trust the user input, always validate and escape the data.

Changed:

`$player = $_POST['Player'];`

to:

`$player = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Player']);`

Added:

```
 // Select time for this player if available
 $query = "SELECT time FROM playersthatvoted WHERE player = '$player' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 0, 1";
 $result = mysql_query($query);


if($result)
   {
       $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
       $last_visit = $row[0];
       $vote_allowed_time = $last_visit + 86400; 

       // Allowed to vote
       if($time > $vote_allowed_time)
       {
           // Do whatever else you need to here ...

           setcookie ("24Hourvote",$ip,time()+86400,'/');
       }
       else
       {
           echo 'This player has already voted today! Come back later...';
       }
   }
   else
   {
       ...
   }
```

**UPDATE**

I would like to highlight the fact that as it stands anyone can enter the player name and try to vote for it and that does not necessarily mean the same user who clicks the vote button.

Additionally the IP address is not being used for any purposes, it may be an idea to use this for further permission/security checks.

Comment: Thank you so much! Would you like me to send you any money for helping me when I get paid for this project?

Comment: Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /home/content/83/8839583/html/Endcraftredeem.php on line 12

Comment: Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/content/83/8839583/html/Endcraftredeem.php on line 12

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/83/8839583/html/Endcraftredeem.php:12) in /home/content/83/8839583/html/Endcraftredeem.php on line 34

Comment: And could I possibly get some info to contact you further if I ever need any help?

Comment: I've updated the code above the issue appears to be with the mysql_real_escape_string(), I believe this possibly due to the fact there is no database connection made by the time that function is called. I use PDO to connect with databases instead, which is a much safer and secure way to connect.

Comment: Im still getting the same errors, i noticed it said you edited in the last 2 minutes so i copypasted the script

Comment: It is not giving off any errors now, but displays a blank page... im adding echos to every aspect of the script to notify the user of where thay end up

Comment: Fully working now :) Im removing all of this to prevent people from stealing this :3

Comment: @Wthrwthr: OMG! Sorry but this platform is all about SHARING questions and answers and you edit the question to prevent people from stealing your code?

Comment: Well, yes, But I didn't know I wasn't allowed to do that

Comment: @ZombieHunter: Well, the revision is still there—see http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8952402/revisions This isn't even effective in hiding the code (nor does it seem appropriate to do so), so I've rolled it back.

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like you already know what you have to do:

> I wanted this script to **store the last visit time in a table**
>   against the user id in a database.Then do a **time calculation** and
>   back them out until the 24 hour expiry time.

So:

1. Forget about the cookie. It is stored on client side and can be manipulated.
2. Before count the vote check the [lastvisit] field of the current user.
3. If not set count the vote and set the [lastvisit] field in your table to the current date.
4. If set calculate the time span between now and the last vote. If bigger than 24 hours, count the vote and set the [lastvisit] field in your table to the current date.

Be aware of:

- Manipulated parameters: `$_POST['Player'];`
- SQL injections: `VALUES ('".$player."', '".$input."')`

If you have problems with one of these tasks then ask about the specific problem.

Comment: can you explain just a bit more on how to do this?

Comment: That answer is extremely helpful, but seems a little vague, Can you possibly give me some example code snippets?

Comment: @Wthrwthr: It only seems to be vague. Providing you with code nearly does the job and I'm not the person to write code for free unless it is a nice open source project. Also your code snippet requires a full review which takes some time.

Comment: The reason this is difficult for me is because I have no prior experience with php and mysql interactions